# How do I wait for a handler's response before continuing processing?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I'm currently working with Google Drive's .NET APIs and I'm trying to download multiple files off my drive. The code google uses in their sample can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads) (my version below)

In .NET Core console project I'm looping through a list of files and trying to download them one at a time, as such:

```
foreach (var file in driveFiles) {
    var fileId = file.Id;
    var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
    var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

    // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
    // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
    // download is completed or failed.
    request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
        (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                    break;
                }
            case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                    break;
                }
            case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                    break;
                }
        }
    };
    request.Download(stream);

    // .. carry on processing
}
```

The problem I have is that I have a list of about 300 files. The code above fires off all 300 downloads at the same time and I'm seeing the progress of each download as it happens. What I *want* to happen is that each download happens one at a time ie. I fire off the first download, and the code waits until that download is complete before moving onto the next one.

I tried to do so by setting a boolean that's only updated once the download completes or fails but this doesn't seem to work:

```
foreach (var file in driveFiles) {
        var fileId = file.Id;
        var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        bool processingComplete = false;

        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.
        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
            (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                        break;
                    }
                case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                        processingComplete = true;
                        break;
                    }
                case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                        processingComplete = true;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        };
        request.Download(stream);

        while (!processingComplete) ;

        processingComplete = false;
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to work and the code seems to continue with the same behaviour.

I'm a little confused about what to do. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Does `request.Download` have correspondent `request.DownloadAsync` method?

Comment: You can encapsulate each downloading file inside a Task, after this you can run it one after one, by this  way you will be sure that only one file will be downloaded at time .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So following on from Fabio's comment, it seems request does have a DownloadAsync method. I've implemented this and this seemed to sort the problem for me:

```
foreach (var file in driveFiles) {
        var fileId = file.Id;
        var request = driveService.Files.Get(fileId);
        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        // Add a handler which will be notified on progress changes.
        // It will notify on each chunk download and when the
        // download is completed or failed.
        request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged +=
                (IDownloadProgress progress) =>
        {
                switch (progress.Status)
                {
                        case DownloadStatus.Downloading:
                                {
                                        Console.WriteLine(progress.BytesDownloaded);
                                        break;
                                }
                        case DownloadStatus.Completed:
                                {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Download complete.");
                                        break;
                                }
                        case DownloadStatus.Failed:
                                {
                                        Console.WriteLine("Download failed.");
                                        break;
                                }
                }
        };

        IDownloadProgress result = await request.DownloadAsync(stream);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you are starting a seperate task for each file. Even if I can not figure out wich part of your code actually *does* the multitasking here. I see none of the obvious culptrips, like await, Threads or the like here. What you need is one task, that runs the loop. Basically you got to wait for on request to finish, before going to the next itteartion.

Generally it is not beneficial to do "per file" Multitasking. Usually the bottleneck is something like the Disk or Network. Networking is a fringe case - it *can* be and often is beneficial to download multiple files at the same time, even from the same endpoint. With a google API, they might be served by different servers (geocasts IIRC), there might be Bandwidth throttlng in place on the Providers side, etc.